# Converting innerHTML content back to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have data that I receive from PHP as an array or array, for example: `[[1, "<p>hello</p><img src='blah.jpg'/>"], [2, "blah, blah"].....etc]` I then display this data in a div. Afterwards, I go through each image in the displayed output and change the src and add attributes. Afterwards, I get the `.innerHTML` of that div and place it in a variable.

**JavaScript**

```
var data = <?php echo $data; ?>;

document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = data;

var images = document.querySelectorAll("img");

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i){
    /*Get image path*/
    var tempSrc = images[i].src; 
    var imgName = tempSrc.split("/").pop();

    /*Change image path to loading image*/
    images[i].src = "../../resources/media/assets/650x450.png";

    images[i].setAttribute('data-src', tempSrc);
    images[i].setAttribute('data-mobile-src', "/stories/media/images/small-images/" + imgName);

}

var transformedData = document.getElementById("info").innerHTML;
console.log(transformedData);
```

The problem that I am facing is that I want to parse `transformedData` back into JSON, but I can't because now `transformedData` is back to a regular string. How do I make it so that `transformedData` is back to an array of arrays?

**Some notes**

var data = `<?php echo $data; ?>;` data for example looks like this: `[[1, "<p>hello</p><img src='blah.jpg'/>"]`, `[2, "blah, blah"].....etc]` When I do `console.log(typeof(data))` it returns as object So it's already parsed as JSON

`JSON.parse()` does not work the error I get is: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1` This is how transformed data looks: `1,<p>blah, blah</p>, 2, <p>blah</p>, etc.` So it's not in array format anymore

Comment: The format 

    [[1, "<p>hello</p><img src='blah.jpg'/>"], [2, "blah, blah"].....etc]
is not a JSON object. If you have control in php assign the value to javascript variable in server itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you're doing after getting the data is shoving it into `#info`, which calls `Array.toString()` on your data and is lossy. Instead, work with the array for as long as you can before sending it out for display. You can create a DOM element for each HTML string in your data, do work on that element, and send the transformed data into a new array.

```js
const data = [
  [1, "<p>hello</p><img src='blah.jpg'/>"],
  [2, "blah, blah"]
];

const transformedData = data.map(a => {
  const div = document.createElement('div'); // whatever #info is
  div.innerHTML = a[1];

  const images = div.querySelectorAll("img");
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
    /*Get image path*/
    var tempSrc = images[i].src;
    var imgName = tempSrc.split("/").pop();

    /*Change image path to loading image*/
    images[i].src = "../../resources/media/assets/650x450.png";

    images[i].setAttribute('data-src', tempSrc);
    images[i].setAttribute('data-mobile-src', "/stories/media/images/small-images/" + imgName);
  }

  return [a[0], div.innerHTML];
});

document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = transformedData;
console.log(transformedData);
```

```html
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want! I was almost going to go for a last resort solution of creating delimiters in the stringed array so I can convert it back into an array, but I'm happy you posted your solution!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at JSON functions as

> JSON.stringify()

or

> JSON.parse()

Note values passed must be valid.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` doesn't work because it's just makes it into a string. transformedData is no longer an array. `JSON.parse()` does not work the error I get is: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1` This is how transformed data looks: `1,<p>blah, blah</p>, 2, <p>blah</p>, etc.` So it's not in array format anymore

Answer (score 0):

If you string now looks like this `<p>a</p> <p>b</p>`, just put some class on your `p` tags witch you want to collect back in `JSON`. Then you need to build array of `p` tags text content, but this array must be string. You can do something like this:

```
let arr = documents.getElementsByClassName('yourClass') 
let strArray = '['
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
   strArray += arr[i].textContent + ', '
} 
strArray += arr[arr.length - 1].textContent
JSON.parse(strArray + ']')
```

Comment: `JSON.parse()` does not work the error I get is: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1` This is how transformed data looks: `1,<p>blah, blah</p>, 2, <p>blah</p>, etc.` So it's not in array format anymore

Comment: Check out the updated answer and let me know is this works.

Answer (score 0):

You format is cannot be parsed as JSON explicitly. Either you have to traverse through loops to format it or If you have control over your php code, assign javascript variables in server itself. You can define two variables

1. JSON
2. HTML String